# pandas true outer join?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, outer-join

How do you get a true outer join in pandas?  Meaning that it actually gives you the entire output instead of combining the columns to merge on.  This is kind of silly in my opinion because it then makes it hard to determine what kind of operation to do on a row.  I do this all the time to detect whether I should Insert, Update, or Delete data, however I always have to create extra copies of the merge on columns, which is just a bunch of overhead (sometimes massive amounts) on certain data sets.

example:

```
import pandas as pd

keys = ["A","B"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":["one","two","three"],"C":["testThis","testThat", "testThis"],"D":[None,hash("B"),hash("C")]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[2,3,4],"B":["two","three","four"],"C":["testThis","testThat", "testThis"], "D":[hash("G"),hash("C"),hash("D")]})

fullJoinDf = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", left_on=keys, right_on=keys, suffixes=["","_r"])
display(
    fullJoinDf,
)

    A   B       C           D               C_r          D_r
0   1   one     testThis    NaN             NaN          NaN
1   2   two     testThat    -3.656526e+18   testThis    -9.136326e+18
2   3   three   testThis    -8.571400e+18   testThat    -8.571400e+18
3   4   four    NaN         NaN             testThis    -4.190116e+17
```

Noticed how it output `A` & `B` magically combined to a single set of columns.  What I want is what I would get in SQL outerjoins etc like:

```
    A    B      C           D               A_r  B_r     C_r        D_r
0   1    one    testThis    NaN             NaN  NaN     NaN        NaN     
1   2    two    testThat    -3.656526e+18   2    two     testThis   -9.136326e+18
2   3    three  testThis    -8.571400e+18   3    three   testThat   -8.571400e+18
3   NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN             4    four    testThis   -4.190116e+17
```

**Edit for @Felipe Whitaker**

Using concat:

```
df3 = df1.copy().set_index(keys)
df4 = df2.copy().set_index(keys)
t = pd.concat([df3,df4], axis=1)
t.reset_index(), 

    A   B       C           D               C           D
0   1   one     testThis    NaN             NaN         NaN
1   2   two     testThat    -3.656526e+18   testThis    -9.136326e+18
2   3   three   testThis    -8.571400e+18   testThat    -8.571400e+18
3   4   four    NaN         NaN             testThis    -4.190116e+17
```

**EDIT Examples***
Given the answers I'm posting more tests, so anyone else who stumbles on this can see a few more of the "gatcha" variations I've discovered while doing this.

```
import pandas as pd

keys = ["A","B"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":["one","two","three"],"C":["testThis","testThat", "testThis"],"D":[None,hash("B"),hash("C")]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[2,3,4],"B":["two","three","four"],"C":["testThis","testThat", "testThis"], "D":[hash("G"),hash("C"),hash("D")]})

df3 = df1.copy()
df4 = df2.copy()
df3.index = df3[keys]
df4.index = df4[keys]

df5 = df1.copy().set_index(keys)
df6 = df2.copy().set_index(keys)


fullJoinDf = df5.merge(df6, how="outer", left_on=keys, right_on=keys, suffixes=["","_r"])
fullJoinDf_2 = df3.merge(df4, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=["","_r"])
t = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, keys=["A","B"])
display(
    df3.index,
    df5.index,
    fullJoinDf,
    fullJoinDf_2,
    t,
)

Index([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')], dtype='object')
MultiIndex([(1,   'one'),
            (2,   'two'),
            (3, 'three')],
           names=['A', 'B'])

    A   B       C           D               C_r         D_r
0   1   one     testThis    NaN             NaN         NaN
1   2   two     testThat    -3.656526e+18   testThis    -9.136326e+18
2   3   three   testThis    -8.571400e+18   testThat    -8.571400e+18
3   4   four    NaN         NaN             testThis    -4.190116e+17

            A    B      C           D               A_r  B_r    C_r        D_r
(1, one)    1.0  one    testThis    NaN             NaN  NaN    NaN        NaN
(2, two)    2.0  two    testThat    -3.656526e+18   2.0  two    testThis    -9.136326e+18
(3, three)  3.0  three  testThis    -8.571400e+18   3.0  three  testThat    -8.571400e+18
(4, four)   NaN  NaN    NaN         NaN             4.0  four   testThis    -4.190116e+17

    A   B       C           D               A   B       C           D
0   1   one     testThis    NaN             2   two     testThis    -9136325526401183790
1   2   two     testThat    -3.656526e+18   3   three   testThat    -8571400026927442160
2   3   three   testThis    -8.571400e+18   4   four    testThis    -419011572131270498
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pd.concat(iter, axis = 1`)?

Comment: @FelipeWhitaker - concat seems to do the same thing, see edit.

Comment: I truly though it would just concatenate them. This result is counter intuitive. Well, thanks.

Comment: Aren't you asking for a column-wise concat, not an outer join (it's only a join if there's at least common column, right?)? I can't understand your example, please edit to clarify what you mean by *"This is kind of silly in my opinion because it then makes it hard to determine what kind of operation to do on a row."*? Isn't that why we usually design schemas to have some primary key(/id) across database tables? If not, how can we make sense of your data?

Comment: I don't see what your schema gains from having two columns `"A":[1,2,3],"B":["one","two","three"]` with different incompatible id's, it just looks like a bad schema design to me if you intend it to work with joins and merges.

Comment: @smci, it is an example.  I could also argue that in many cases, schema is no choice of mine, but something I'm forced to work with once I receive data.  The real application here is to compare incoming data against current IDs and hashed rows, to determine how to handle the incoming rows efficiently.  Always open to better suggestions for process.

Comment: @JamieMarshall: pick one of `A`,`B` to be your index (presumably `A`), do `df.set_index('A')`, drop `B`. Now you can easily do joins (outer joins or left joins). What am I missing? (Do you need the result to be mergeable back to the source database? Honestly that is a bad schema design, perhaps you can reeducate your customer gradually...)

Comment: @smci - but if A,B are my keys, I have a multi key index.  You can't throw away one specified key and hope the dataset will remain consistent.  If its a multikey index, its a multikey index.  I don't know anyway of getting around that other than being psychic ;)

Comment: @JamieMarshall then do `df.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True)` to use the multiindex. Can you explain precisely how the join doesn't do what you need? I still say you're looking for a vertical concat, not an outer join - can you please edit the title?

Comment: @smci - The problem is if it returns the 'A' and 'B' columns combined together in the output its hard to determine which data set didn't result in a match, the right or the left.  If the 'A' and 'B' remain separate I can simply test the left 'A' for null and determine those rows are to be inserted (assuming 'A' is my persistent set.)  Where 'A' right is null I can determine those records are to be deleted from my persistent set.  Where they are both present I know those records are for update.  That way I can read the data once, and process the set efficiently there after.

Comment: @JamieMarshall: so, convert the multi-index down to single index (e.g. by using a dict), save it for later, do your joins/concats, then translate the single-index back to multi-index. Can you try that yourself, post your code and explain where it goes wrong?

Comment: @smci - I guess on your other point, I am asking for a column wise concat, but the example posted shows concat also combines the indexes, quite annoyingly.

Comment: @JamieMarshall: concat doesn't concat indices as long as they're set as indices, not ordinary columns. That's why I keep urging you to fix the index first before you start doing joins/concats.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223729/discussion-between-jamie-marshall-and-smci).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care abut the original indexes at all:

```
df1.index = df1[keys]
df2.index = df2[keys]

fullJoinDf = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=["","_r"])
```

Result:

```
     A      B         C             D  A_r    B_r       C_r           D_r
0  1.0    one  testThis           NaN  NaN    NaN       NaN           NaN
1  2.0    two  testThat  6.368540e+18  2.0    two  testThis -6.457388e+18
2  3.0  three  testThis -7.490461e+18  3.0  three  testThat -7.490461e+18
3  NaN    NaN       NaN           NaN  4.0   four  testThis  4.344649e+18
```

Comment: `df1.index = df1[keys]` is just a disguised `df1.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True, drop=False)` which is what should have been done on the dataframe in the first place.

Comment: @smci - your comment is incorrect.  `df1.index = df1[keys]`, returns a different result from `df1.set_index(['A','B'])`.  This is the entire crux of the problem and why all my examples above don't work, but this answer does.

Comment: @JamieMarshall: this is using a list-of-tuples as index instead of a pandas MultiIndex. Really it seems like an XY problem to kludge the equivalence of the index columns 'A' and 'B', in a non-pandas way. This doesn't seem like a good idiom, and can you guarantee pandas can handle or won't mangle this dataframe in any further operations? (join, merge, reset_index etc. reset_index() doesn't work, for one)

Comment: @smci - bottom line, `set_index` doesn't work.  I don't see how there's a way around this unless you can keep `set_index` from eating up the index columns.  I can't.

Comment: @JamieMarshall: I already showed you that `df1.set_index(['A','B'], inplace=True, drop=False)` prevents pandas eating up the index columns. You missed the crucial `drop=False` part. Also `inplace=True` to prevent unwanted copying. I think this is what you wanted; if not please explain specifically why not.

Answer (score 2):

if you rename the columns used in the merge in 1 of the DataFrames before the `merge` it looks like it will give the correct answer

```
df1.merge(df2.rename({'A': 'A_y', 'B': 'B_y'}, axis =1), left_on=keys, right_on=['A_y', 'B_y'], how='outer')
#output:
    A   B       C_x         D_x             A_y     B_y     C_y         D_y
0   1.0 one     testThis    NaN             NaN     NaN     NaN         NaN
1   2.0 two     testThat    -2.482945e+18   2.0     two     testThis    -1.215774e+18
2   3.0 three   testThis    1.140152e+17    3.0     three   testThat    1.140152e+17
3   NaN NaN     NaN         NaN             4.0     four    testThis    -4.915382e+18
```

Comment: I marked @CodeDifferent right, but this maybe the faster operation.  Setting the index requires the hole column, to be reset, this may be the more efficient  Will have to test to find out.